# JavaScript, AngularJS - sending multiple simultaneous ajax calls

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, promise, es6-promise

In my `AngularJS` application I have an array of parameters (some IDs, for example), which should be used as a parameters for an ajax call queue. The problem is that array might contain more than 600 items and if I just recursively make the ajax call using the `forEach` loop,  the browser page eventually stops responding before each of the requests are resolved, since each of responses updates the view. Is there a technique, which could allow to send ajax requests, for example, by 5 requests at a time asynchronously, and only when those are finished, proceed the next 5?

Comment: do you need to update the view after all finished or after each one finished?
Promise.all ??

Comment: @IlyaNovojilov - or a third option, after each "batch" of 5 have finished

Comment: Wait, you plan on sending 600 requests?

Comment: yes, there's a lot of information to show on the screen, and I have a 'show all' functionality, which in summary takes 600+ requests to make.

Comment: You never should do that. Either change your API to answer multiple queries per request, or at least use lazy loading to request only the information the user is currently viewing. Sending 600 requests at once is a no-go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think best solution would be to change the endpoint to allow an array of Id's, but I guess that is not an option. You can use promises to limit the number of simultaneous requests:

```
function chunkedAjax(idArray, index, limit) {
  if(index >= idArray.length) {
    return;
  }
  var index = index || 0;
  var limit = limit || 5;

  var chunk = idArray.slice(index, limit);
  var promises = [];

  angular.forEach(chunk, function(id) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    promises.push(deferred.promise);
    makeAjaxCall(id).then(function(response){
      deferred.resolve();
    });
  });

  $q.all(promises).then(function() {
    chukedAjax(idArray, index + limit, limit);
  });

}
```

This is a recursive function, so be warned. I would debug this heavily before putting into production.

You will also likely need to modify your `makeAjaxCall` function to return a promise if it does not already, or pass the promise object to it so that it can be resolved when the ajax call completes

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [$q.all()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q). This lets you execute a callback if multiple requests have finished. And therefore you are able to recursively execute a limited number of requests until all items are processed.

Comment: re-read the question - OP wants to limit the number of active requests

Comment: You are right. But my idea was to partition the 600 requests and use some recursion where the next `n` requests are fired if the success callback is called.

Comment: seems like the "answer: was lacking this information

Comment: Also lacking an example

Answer (score -1):

Yes!

Take a look on this module: https://github.com/caolan/async